# Keep asking for input and reopen stdin

Tags: c++, stdin, eof

I have a task to create a program that does some calculation on a vector of numbers. The vector must contain at least 1 number in it and if it doesn't I have to throw an exception and try again. There is a video example how the code should work here: https://asciinema.org/a/283343

I'm guessing that EOF is being signaled using CTRL+D and that's what causes the exception to be thrown.
If they were using Enter (new line), it would leave a blank line behind.
But in my case, after I press CTRL+D, my program just runs in an infinite loop because the stdin stays in a failed state despite me using cin.clear().

Is there another shortcut similar to CTRL+D that they might be using for this, or is there a way to reopen the stream, or restart the whole application.

The program runs fine on Windows when I use CTRL+Z, but on Linux I just can't get it to work the same.

Example code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

void enter_elements(std::vector<double>& input_list){
    double x;
    std::cout << "Enter numbers: " << std::endl;
    while(std::cin >> x){
        input_list.push_back(x);
    }
    if(input_list.empty()){
        throw std::string("You must enter at least 1 number!");
    }

}

int main(){
    std::vector<double> input_list;

    try {
    enter_elements(input_list);
    } catch (const std::string& e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e << std::endl;
        std::cin.clear();
        enter_elements(input_list);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this problem or suggest where could I maybe read more about it?

Comment: Two things of the top of my head: First of all is that this doesn't seem to be a good use-case for exceptions; The second thing is that you might want to use a special sentinel input to mark the end of the input rather than end-of-file.

Comment: Oh and a third thing: You probably want to call `enter_elements` in a loop until the vector is non-empty. Right now you only make two attempts.

Comment: I was thinking about calling the main() instead of enter_elements(list) so that way I would basically "restart" my program.

Comment: Oh you can't do that. Calling [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) yourself is forbidden in C++, and leads to *undefined behavior*. If you want a loop, use an actual loop.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Once the stream is closed, the stream is closed. That's it.

What I'd do is accept a set of numbers *on one line*. Your input iteration would end at the end of the line. Then you validate those numbers, and ask for another line if necessary.

You can do that by looping over `std::getline` instead of using formatted extraction. Then you'd need to parse the line you get.

That's not what the video shows, but I don't know how they achieved that. Maybe you should ask them!

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to stop the program?
If so, on linux, you should try `CTRL+C` instead of `CTRL+D` or `CTRL+Z` while your program is running

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of reason why I hate using cin >> anInt. I much prefer to getLine and parse it myself. Then you can make it do anything and decide how you're going to determine end of list, etc.

Yes, it's more code. But you don't run into these weird problems like this.

Comment: I tried going that route, but still, when I signal CTRL+D, std::cin stays in a failed state even after using std::cin.ignore(), and the program gets into an infinite loop..

Comment: True, which is why you would want a different way to end your input -- like a blank line.